# Firebase 'ChildHas' is not working properly in js

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Why does the console say that `groupRef` is not a function in this snippet of code?

```
var groupRef = db.ref('Whatsapp' +'/'+ input_url);

groupRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.hasChild(input_url)) {
     alert('exists');
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see any usage of `groupRef` as a function in the code you shared, so it seems unlikely the error comes from (just) this snippet. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I have a feeling this is not a complete repro, and the problem is probably caused by someting we can't see.